# Create ButterKnife.bind in BaseFragment

Tags: android, butterknife

I have BaseFragment

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    protected Unbinder unbinder;


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

In this BaseFragment I have Unbinder  and call unbind(); after onDestroy. But create it in child Fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catigories_fragment, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        init();
        return view;
    }
```

How can I move unbinder  creation to BaseFragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I move unbinder creation to BaseFragment?

I would rather keep it as it, letting the subclass the responsibility of initializing `unbinder` when `onCreateView` is called, but if you really want to move it and the implementation of `onCreateView` doesn't  change, the only missing piece of information is the id of the layout (`R.layout.catigories_fragment` in this case) the different subclasses want to use. A solution could be to declare a getter in your `BaseFragment`

```
 protected int getLayoutId() {
    return 0;
 }
```

and use it for the  `inflater.inflate`. Eg.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = null; 
   if (getLayoutId() != 0) {
        view = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        init();
    }
    return view;
}
```

and onDestroy

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (unbinder != null) {
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thing much easier use protected Unbinder unbinder; and create in each child Fragment)))

Comment: well, it was you that ask `How can I move unbinder creation to BaseFragment?`

Comment: Yes. Of course, this is exactly what I asked. thanks for the answer! just after the answer I decided that my implementation is not bad. do you think it's worthwhile to move unbinder creation to the base fragment?

Comment: I think it is pointless, but I would still keep the protected member in the base class

Answer (score 0):

This question has been over for two years, and I am here to share another solution. The advantage of this solution is that you only need to mark the activity or fragment that need to be bound, and the binding / unbinding will happen automatically.

1.Create a Fragment base class and add some helpers.

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
    var unbinder: Unbinder? = null

    fun bind() {
        unbind()
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view!!)
    }

    fun unbind() {
        unbinder?.unbind()
        unbinder = null
    }
}
```

2. Declare an interface to identify the Activity / Fragment to be bound.

```
/**
* Marks an activity / fragment needs to be bound by [ButterKnife].
*/
interface Bindable
```

3. Create an object and register the Activity / Fragment lifecycle callback.

```
/**
 * Helper class to automatically inject fragments if they implement [Bindable].
 */
object AppInjector {

    fun init(application: App) {
        application
            .registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
                override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                    handleActivity(activity)
                }

                override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {

                }

                override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {

                }

                override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {

                }

                override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {

                }

                override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle?) {

                }

                override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {

                }
            })
    }

    private fun handleActivity(activity: Activity) {
        if (activity is FragmentActivity) {
            activity.supportFragmentManager
                .registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
                    object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {

                        override fun onFragmentViewCreated(
                            fm: FragmentManager,
                            f: Fragment,
                            v: View,
                            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
                        ) {
                            if (f is BaseFragment && f is Bindable) {
                                f.bind()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFragmentDestroyed(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
                            if (f is BaseFragment && f is Bindable) {
                                f.unbind()
                            }
                        }
                    }, true
                )
        }
    }
}
```

4. Register these callbacks in your Application subclass.

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        AppInjector.init(this)
    }
}
```

5. Mark your Fragment is bindable and use `Butterknife` as usual.

```
class WelcomeFragment : BaseFragment(), Bindable {

    @BindView(R.id.fragment_welcome_loginButton)
    lateinit var loginButton: Button

    @BindView(R.id.fragment_welcome_emailSignUpButton)
    lateinit var emailSignUpButton: SignUpButton

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_welcomeFragment_to_loginFragment)
        )

        emailSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_welcomeFragment_to_signUpFragment)
        )
    }

}
```

I didn't implement this for activity because I don't need it, you can implement it yourself.